# Error using while loop in java

Tags: c#, java, console

I'm a newbie in java from c# background. In c# when i want to make sure the user cannot does null data in the Console Application i make a loop like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your name : ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    while (name == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name : ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement the same in java. I am using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
    String pname;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    pname=scan.next();

    while ("".equals(pname))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
        pname=scan.next();
    }
}
```

But when a null value is entered, the output doesn't show the `Enter your name` again it only moves one line waiting for a value to be entered.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you enter a `null` value?

Comment: @Joni By just hitting the enter key without typing anything. Thats how its done in c#. I am making a mistake?

Comment: "While loop doesn't work well in java", hilarious title, isn't it? I wonder how can you think that the language is not working well instead of you since you even admit to be a newbie.

Comment: @Jack Sorry pls can u help me edit. just didn't know what to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `nextLine()` instead. `next()` only gets up to the next space, `nextLine()` gets the next linebreak. I vaguely remember this from my java class in college.

Comment: Did my answer offend you..?

Comment: Usually when people have several `.....` at the end, it implies sarcasm. (I'm glad it wasn't in this case lol)

Comment: Lol i never knew that

Comment: I bet it's a culture thing. Anyways, glad I could help, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while ("".equals(pname))
        {
           System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
           pname=scan.next();
        }
```

Instead use

```
     while (pname.equals(""))
     {
        System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
        pname=scan.next();
     }
```

If you look at javadocs for equals, you will know what i am talking about.
And also a hint, i started using buffred reader when i started coding in java

Comment: This won't make a difference because `equals` is symmetric. Actually the original is preferred if there's a chance `pname` is actually `null`.

Comment: This is not correct. If pname is NULL, in the second form you obtain a `NullPointerException` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while (pname == null || "".equals(pname))
{
    System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
    pname = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar type of problem once. The problem is not in while loop. It is in reusing same Scanner object. Try creating new Scanner object each time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO code application logic here
System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
String pname;
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
pname=scan.next();

while (pname.equals(""))
{
    System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    pname=scan.next();
}
```

}